# How to call C++ functions with different signatures through function pointer

Tags: c++, functor

I have a C++ application where main() instantiates an object, MyApp, and then passes the object to a ReadConfig function.

ReadConfig opens a text based file, parses it, and calls the appropriate MyApp methods to configure it.

```
class MyApp
{
private:

public:
  void SetRate(uint16_t);
  void EnableLogging(bool);
  void SetAddress(uint32_t);
};
```

I'm trying to make it easy to maintain ReadConfig such that as new public methods are added to MyApp, it can be as simple as updating a table.  I have come up with the following solution but I don't like it.  It's hard to maintain due to having to make sure I put 0s in the right place.

Below is a example of what I've been able to work out.  Any advice to make this better would be appreciated.  Note I work in embedded so the C++ compilers we use don't support C++14 & there is no boost.  And I would like to avoid using any STL libraries so as to understand the mechanics of doing this myself.

Here is what I have:

```
enum ARGTYPE {TBOOL, TUINT16, TUINT32};

template<typename TOBJ, typename TARG>
struct TSetting
{
  void (TOBJ::*FSet)(TARG);
};

template<typename obj>
struct SETTINGFN
{
  const char                       *setting_name;
  ARGTYPE                          Targ;
  TSetting<obj,bool>               HBool;
  TSetting<obj,uint16_t>           HUint16;
  TSetting<obj,uint32_t>           HUint32;
};

SETTINGFN<MyApp> MyAppSettings[] =
{
  "logging"    ,TBOOL,       &MyApp::EnableLogging, 0,0,0
  ,"maxrate"   ,TUINT16,     0,0,0,&MyApp::SetRate
  ,"address"   ,TUINT32,     0, &MyApp::SetAddress, 0,0

};
unsigned int MyAppSettings_Count = sizeof(MyAppSettings) / sizeof(SETTINGFN<MyApp>);
```

Then as I read the config file and parse it, I call a function to handle calling the actual MyApp functions through the function pointers.  That function is as follows:

```
bool AppSetting(MyApp &E, TObjnode &node)
{
  bool rval = false;

  for(unsigned int i=0; i<MyAppSettings_Count && !rval; i++)
  {
    if(node.GetName() == MyAppSettings[i].setting_name)
    {
      rval = true;

      switch(MyAppSettings[i].Targ)
      {
        case TBOOL:
          (E.*MyAppSettings[i].HBool.FSet)(node.GetValue().AsBool());
        break;

        case TUINT16:
          (E.*MyAppSettings[i].HUint16.FSet)(node.GetValue().Value());
        break;

        case TUINT32:
          (E.*MyAppSettings[i].HUint32.FSet)(node.GetValue().Value());
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return(rval);
}
```

Comment: Considered passing a string to each setter, and letting them call the type-specific reusable parsing code?  Then all setters can be the same type.  A trampoline that accepts string, and calls both the parsing function and the type-safe setter might be even better.

Comment: So... to avoid having to add a function call to your configuration dispatch routine each time a new property / setter is added, you want to update a proprietary data structure each time a new property / setter is added?  To each his own, I suppose...

Comment: I thought of these but I was hoping to avoid changing the current function signatures or adding new ones

Comment: Is there a reason you are using such a complicated scheme just for application configuration?

Comment: Oh bump, cannot edit comment after 5 minutes. Anyway what I wanted to add:

Anyway what I once tried, and sticked to, is dead simple yet super effective approach similar to something described in here: https://blog.molecular-matters.com/2011/06/27/config-values/

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger yes because I think the for-loop is faster than a bunch of if, else if, else if calls.  The code shown is just an example.  The real code has, currently, 30 to 40 settings.  But what do I know, I'm here asking because I'm looking for feedback on how others do it.

Comment: @AdrianLis I looked at the link you gave and it seems more complicated than what I did but I see how it can simplify one part at the expense of creating a class for each type.  Thanks for the info.  Will study it further.

Comment: @Eric - Even if optimizing at that level were a good idea (which it isn't), when you look at what the for loop is doing there is no reason to think it would be faster.  Actually probably the opposite.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I would respectfully disagree (this is beyond the main topic). 1st, optimizing at this level is important for start up time.  This code runs on an ARM-M4 processor in the embedded space.  If you look at the ASM, for loops generally are faster than if, else-if.  Some compiler optimize better than others.  I will dump the ASM if you're interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thorn in your design is the different parameter types.

If the parameters are abstracted into a structure, then the functions can be simplified to one fixed signature.

By using a base structure, the signatures and be more generic:

```
struct Arguments_Base
{
};

void SetRate(Arguments_Base& ab);
void EnableLogging(Arguments_Base& ab);
void SetAddress(Arguments_Base& ab);
```

By having uniform signatures, *function pointers* or *function objects* can be used in tables or maps, making searching easier.  The search engines should be able to be generic and depend on the size of the data so that only the data (e.g. table) needs to be changed, not the search engine.

Each type of set of arguments should be derived from the `Arguments_Base` class.  The function can then `dynamic_cast` the base class reference.

See also: Factory Design Pattern, Visitor Design Pattern, Double Dispatch

Comment: believe it or not, I thought of this but I was hoping to avoid changing the current function signatures or adding new ones - but this is elegant.

Comment: @rubenvb a dynamic cast would not be needed if the base class provided a method that the derived classes could then overload.  Think NVI design pattern.  Alternatively, the base class could simply just do the conversion if ,like Ben Voigt suggest, Arguments_Base is, instead, a String class that can return values (ints, bools, etc...)

Comment: @Eric yes, that sounds more like it :).